# Creating matrix to represent values of multiple rasters?

Tags: r, matrix, classification

I want to find the location of a good field location where it finds good locations regarding the values I put for 3 different rasters. I have made a test code so you know what I want.

```
library(raster) # raster
library(terra) # # essential package for manipulation of raster data
library(sf) # essential package for manipulation of vector spatial data

# dem of NZ
dem <- rast("dem_300m.tif")

# distance from roads (additional)
roads_dist <- rast("roads_dist.tif")

# slope
# computing slope based on digital elevation model (DEM)
dem_slope <- terrain(dem, v="slope", n=4, unit="degrees")

# plotting of slope
plot(dem_slope, main = "Slope (in degrees)", col = brewer.pal(9, "Oranges"))

# we need slope but this time in radians
#dem_slope_rad <- terrain(dem_south_island_mask, v="slope", n=4, unit="radians")

# elevation
# data reclassification
# using cuts of 1200, 1700, 2500 and max value
dem_reclassified <- classify(dem, c(0,1200,1700,2500,Inf), include.lowest = T) 


# change names using factors
levels(dem_reclassified) <- c("NA","1","2","NA")
plot(dem_reclassified, col = terrain.colors(3))

# slope
slope_reclassified <- classify(dem_slope, c(0,15,30,45,Inf), include.lowest = T)

# change names using factors
levels(slope_reclassified) <- c("NA","2","1","NA")

# distance
distance_reclassified <- classify(roads_dist, c(0,5000,10000,15000,Inf), include.lowest = T)

# change names using factors
levels(distance_reclassified) <- c("3","2","1","NA")

rec <- c(0,5,NA,
         6,9,1,
         9,Inf,2)

# matrix creation
rec_mat <- matrix(rec, ncol = 3, byrow = T)

# reclassification using matrix
dem_reclassified2 <- classify(dem, rcl = rec_mat)
dem_reclassified2        


# change of names
levels(dem_reclassified2) <- c("NA","Limited Suitability","Suitable")
```

I need to assign levels so only places with more then 6 points are shown: 0-5 points (NA), 6-9 points (1: “Limited suitability”) and more than 9 points (2: “Suitable”) with the points coming from :

```
dem_reclassified <- classify(dem, c(0,1200,1700,2500,Inf), include.lowest = T)
levels(dem_reclassified) <- c("NA","1","2","NA")

slope_reclassified <- classify(dem_slope, c(0,15,30,45,Inf), include.lowest = T)
levels(slope_reclassified) <- c("NA","2","1","NA")

distance_reclassified <- classify(roads_dist, c(0,5000,10000,15000,Inf), include.lowest = T)
levels(distance_reclassified) <- c("3","2","1","NA")
```

then performing the matrix at and trying to plot the map at:

```
rec <- c(0,5,NA,
         5,9,1,
         9,Inf,2)

# matrix creation
rec_mat <- matrix(rec, ncol = 3, byrow = T)

# reclassification using matrix
dem_reclassified2 <- classify(dem, rcl = rec_mat)
dem_reclassified2        

# check categories
levels(dem_reclassified2)

# visual check
plot(dem_reclassified2, col = terrain.colors(3))

# change of names
levels(dem_reclassified2) <- c("NA","Limited Suitability","Suitable")
plot(dem_reclassified2, col = terrain.colors(3))
```

Comment: Should viewers of this Q expect to find a data object named `dem` in the two packages loaded?

Comment: No sorry, I have edited to show where the dem comes from - raster file.

Comment: `Error: [rast] cannot open file: dem_300m.tif` Please, please, please. Leartn to restart your R sesssion with no .Rdata file in the background and run your code to find out what we will encounter. We are not sitting at your machine.